# V.A.T disappears when placing order

Tags: magento, coupon

I set up a coupon code rule in Shopping Cart Price Rules and in system config I set "After Discount" on "Apply Customer Tax" option.

I use firecheckout extension for checkout, and when looking there everything works fine when applying coupon code or not.

BUT, when clicking to place order, all VAT on all orders is deducted/taken off the total amount. Only if I change back to "Before Discount" VAT is working again.

Magento v1.6.2